# Python - Append line under another line that contains a certain string

Tags: python, regex, find, append, line

I want to append the string `"$basetexturetransform" "center .5 .5 scale 4 4 rotate 0 translate 0 0"` (including the quotation marks) as a new line under every line that contains the string `$basetexture`.

So that, for example, the file

```
"LightmappedGeneric"
{
    "$basetexture" "Concrete/concrete_modular_floor001a"
    "$surfaceprop" "concrete"
    "%keywords" "portal"
}
```

turns into

```
"LightmappedGeneric"
{
    "$basetexture" "Concrete/concrete_modular_floor001a"
    "$basetexturetransform" "center .5 .5 scale 4 4 rotate 0 translate 0 0"
    "$surfaceprop" "concrete"
    "%keywords" "portal"
}
```

and I want to do it for every file that has the file extension ".vmt" in a folder (including sub folders).

Is there an easy way to do this in Python? I have like 400 `.vmt` files in a folder that I need to modify and it would be a real pain to have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression might likely do that with `re.sub`:

```
import re

regex = r"(\"\$basetexture\".*)"

test_str = """
"LightmappedGeneric"
{
    "$basetexture" "Concrete/concrete_modular_floor001a"
    "$surfaceprop" "concrete"
    "%keywords" "portal"
}
"LightmappedGeneric"
{
    "$nobasetexture" "Concrete/concrete_modular_floor001a"
    "$surfaceprop" "concrete"
    "%keywords" "portal"
}

"""

subst = "\\1\\n\\t\"$basetexturetransform\" \"center .5 .5 scale 4 4 rotate 0 translate 0 0\""

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE))
```

---

#### Output

```
"LightmappedGeneric"
{
    "$basetexture" "Concrete/concrete_modular_floor001a"
    "$basetexturetransform" "center .5 .5 scale 4 4 rotate 0 translate 0 0"
    "$surfaceprop" "concrete"
    "%keywords" "portal"
}
"LightmappedGeneric"
{
    "$nobasetexture" "Concrete/concrete_modular_floor001a"
    "$surfaceprop" "concrete"
    "%keywords" "portal"
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZHZhc4/1/). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/ZHZhc4/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

#### Reference

[Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! That will probably do the trick for a single file at least. Is there a simple way to extend this to apply it on ALL files with a ".vmt" file extention in a folder (including subfolders)?

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you!